# How do I change the database connection with .net authentication

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-authentication

On my project I use .net Owin Authentication.

I have to change the project to use a new database that is totally identical to the old one, I tried changing the connection string but it didn't work.

This is the code:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base(new DBConn().CnnOldDB(), throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); // This needs to go before the other rules!

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("WebUsers", "dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("WebRoles", "dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("WebUserRoles", "dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("WebUserClaims", "dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("WebUserLogins", "dbo");
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

I tried changing the name of the database as below:

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
                : base(new DBConn().CnnNewDB(), throwIfV1Schema: false)
```

But I got the following error:

> The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since
>   the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to
>   update the database

I researched online but couldn't find a good answer, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to update your database first. Did you run `update-database` in your Package Manager Console

Comment: The problem is no with your connection. The problem is that you create the database, and then made changes to the entities. Are you using migrations? You should use migrations or some method to update your database from your code (Code First) or update your code from your database schema (Database First).

Comment: @user2657943, Yes, I run a `update-database` command but got the following error: `Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (OBJECT) is wrong.` any idea? Thanks!